# Hochschild dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

I'm curious; if $A$ is a commutative $k$-algebra over a field $k$ of global dimension $n$, then is its $A^e$-projective dimension $2n$ (this is also sometimes called the Hochschild cohomological dimension)?

Answer (score 0):

In general no. Take $A=k(X)$= the field of fractions on a set X of trascendent variables. It has global dimension 0 because it is a field, but its Hochschild dimension as k-algebra  = the cardinality of the set $X$.